# Left Join with where clause

Tags: ms-access, left-join, where-clause, sql

I have 3 tables A, B and C

[image]

I am doing this :-
/* There is no relation between Table A and Table B . Table A is just used to provide values to C.Profile */
1st step ) D <---- Select * from C where Profile=1 // want to give a specific ProID(I have successfully retrieved it from A table)

2nd Step ) Output <--- Select B.sname,D.Status from B Left Join D On B.ID=D.ID

so that the output looks like the required output table shown above:-

Can I do this by using a single query? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a subquery:

```
Select B.DirName,D.Status 
from B Left Join (
    Select * 
    from C 
    where ProId=1) As D 
On B.DirID=D.DirID
```

It is best to use a list of fields rather than *

Comment: How much these inner select (inside pranthesis) impose load to database server? Is it sort of heavy query or DB will handle it very smoothly?